# Open Alternate Extension in 'Single Instance' of SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know how to add additional extensions to SQL Server Management Studio, to have them treated just like .sql files. But, when opening them, a new instance of Management Studio is created.

I also see numerous issues posted about double clicking on .SQL files and getting them to open in the existing instance of SQL server. This already works for me.

What doesn't work is the additional extensions I have added. I'm using .PRC. All of the fixes propose changing various registry settings, all which are related to the default .sql extension.

I don't see see how any of these fixes can be applied to make other extensions work or if there is anything else I can do to solve this?

EDIT:

What i've done so far...

1. Copied over all the same settings from [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.sql] to [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.prc].
2. Checked all the settings mentioned in the article on sql server central to fix this issue for .SQL extensions.
3. Configured SSMS file type .PRC with editing experience "SQL Query Editor".
4. I even tried creating a batch file to open the file for me:
   "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" /dde %1

Even the 4th thing I tried opens a new instance, although this is the same call that is configured in the registry for sqlweb.sql.9.0.

Comment: Please use the correct term - you're not talking about multiple instances of SQL Server, but rather multiple instances of SQL Server Management Studio. Anyway, please see [if this helps](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic669665-391-1.aspx) - just use `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.prc\PersistentHandler` for example. As an aside, I don't think this issue exists anymore in the 2012 version of Management Studio, so that might be a more straightforward solution.

Comment: Thanks i updated it. This already works for me. They point out changing the registry settings to SSMS itself and I don't need that since it works already for .sql files. So I'm looking for a solution specific to other extensions.

Comment: Did you notice that some of the updates to the registry talk about paths like `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.sql\PersistentHandler`? Did you see my suggestion to make the same changes to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.prc\PersistentHandler`, which will affect `.prc` files not `.sql` files?

Comment: I didn't see that part, but I tried it just guessing after comparing the registry settings for both extensions and it didn't have any affect. Maybe I need to reboot after making the change. I'll give that another shot. :)

Comment: I got it to work fine in Management Studio 2008. Double-clicking on a new .prc file opens in the same window, not a new window. Now to figure out why `SQL Query Editor` is not an option for custom file extensions in SQL Server 2012...

Comment: I was actually looking at a different setting before. After checking the PersistentHandler... both my .SQL and .PRC have the same value... {5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}. Did you have to add the perceived type to the PRC? Also my default for PRC shows SqlServerReplication.Prc instead of sqlwb.sql.9.0. I thought perhaps SQL server set this when I setup the association and was afraid to change it.

Comment: I would change those. That's what worked for me - make the .prc entries match the .sql entries.

Comment: I've copied over every setting to my .PRC registry entry and rebooted, but I get the same behavior. Since you have this working successfully, I am hoping that I must be missing something else? I also checked every setting mentioned in the article and mine are all the same. Also in SSMS I have the .PRC extension added with editing experience "SQL Query Editor". Anything different from what you have setup?

Comment: Not that I can see, no, except that I also have SQL Server 2012 Management Studio installed (doubt that can be a factor, but who knows).

Comment: I did read somewhere that they fixed the issue with 2012, so maybe it could be a factor. If I have the same exact registry settings as you, then I don't know what else it could be. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved problem of opening PRC file by double click. I simply exported this key from regedit

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.sql
```

Modified this file to look like this

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.PRC]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.PRC\OpenWithList]
"a"="ssms.exe"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.PRC\OpenWithProgids]
"ssms.sql.11.0"=hex(0):
"ssms.sql.12.0"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.PRC\UserChoice]
"Progid"="ssms.sql.12.0"
```

And applied it over registry. The original PRC key I backuped and removed from registry before I applied that new keys. Now PRC file is opened by double click on PRC file in opened instance of SSMS.

But highlighting doesn't work still for me :(

Comment: This should be marked as the Correct Answer as it's exactly the right thing to do. The additional step for fixing syntax highlighting in SSMS is: Go to the Tools, Options..., Text Editor, File Extension and add a "prc" extension that uses the "SQL Query Editor" option, click Add, click OK and party like it's 1999...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be going through a lot of hassle to deal with your source control system. Have you considered making your source control system recognize a different extension for procedures, tables, views, etc. which will prevent you having to make these registry changes on every developer's computer?

```
.proc.sql -> stored procedure
.view.sql -> view
.fn.sql   -> function
```

etc. etc. Surely your source control system can handle longer extensions that contain `.`, and now Management Studio will behave properly with all your file types.

Comment: The issue is really the .PRC extension which is what I'm trying to solve. It's not so much opening them from source control. We just have to use the PRC extension in our source control system because of auto-deployment reasons. I'd have the same issue in any system really.

Comment: But you had to manually configure your source control system to deal with the extension `.PRC`. I'm suggesting you could change it so that your deployment knows a `.prc.sql` file is a stored procedure, instead of a `.prc` file. Is that clearer?

Comment: I didn't configure anything in my source control system. I added the file extension to SSMS so it would treat it like a script when I opened it. I have this issue opening the files from Windows Explorer by double clicking them. I only mentioned the source control to denote why we are naming the files the way we are. It's actually related to deployment. I work for a large company and there is no way they would change extensions, so I'm trying to work around it to make it easier to open the files from windows explorer without having to drag them into SSMS.